# python social auth partial `NOT NULL constraint failed: social_auth_partial.timestamp` with django

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have following pipelines at settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE =(
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'auth_manager.fb_account_linking.save_number',
)
```

my auth_manager.fb_account_linking.py looks like following:

```
@partial
def save_number(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    m = MobileNo.objects.filter(user=user)
    print(len(m))

    if not len(m)>0:
                  return redirect('account_kit')
```

I am getting following error:

```
IntegrityError at /auth/oauth/complete/facebook/
NOT NULL constraint failed: social_auth_partial.timestamp
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: social_auth_partial.timestamp) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py" in wrapper
  50.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\views.py" in complete
  28.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\actions.py" in do_complete
  41.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in complete
  40.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py" in wrapper
  252.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py" in auth_complete
  110.         return self.do_auth(access_token, response, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py" in do_auth
  152.         return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\strategy.py" in authenticate
  115.         return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  115.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in authenticate
  80.         return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in pipeline
  83.         out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in run_pipeline
  113.             result = func(*args, **out) or {}

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\pipeline\partial.py" in wrapper
  34.             strategy.storage.partial.store(current_partial)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\storage.py" in store
  325.         partial.save()

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  808.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  838.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  924.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  963.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1107.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /auth/oauth/complete/facebook/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: social_auth_partial.timestamp
```

Comment: Have run your migrations ?

Comment: run makemigrations than migrate

Comment: already migrated everything. Point to note it works just fine without partials, but I would need them for pause and resume authentication.